# Changing Devise user profile url from .com/users/username to .com/username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently my users profiles are as .com/users/username. How can I make it .com/username? I tried many stuff in routes.rb but I could not make it happen. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using empty `path`:

```
devise_for : users, path: '', controllers: {
    unlocks: 'users/unlocks',
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    passwords: 'users/passwords'
    ...
  }
```

**But**, it's a bad idea. For example, if you have route like `get '/services'` and new user take username `services`. Then you'd have a problem with routes.

**Update**

If you need shortlink, you can using one symbol, like:

```
devise_for : users, path: 'u'
```

Result:

```
domain.com/u/username
```

Comment: ha! as simple as that path: ' ' :D Thank you mate!

Comment: @Designer you are welcome. But remember about root path problem.